Trace logs in SurrealDB
Is there a special function for tracing information, or logging to the console while executing queries in SurrealDB, similar to RAISE in Postgres? I would ideally like to view data without necessarily having to turn it into a string either - as NONE cannot be converted to a string with type::string().

SurrealDB does not have a direct equivalent to PostgreSQL's RAISE for tracing or logging during query execution. However, you can enable trace logging by starting SurrealDB with the --log trace option. This will log detailed information about the database operations to the console, allowing you to view data without converting it to a string format.
You can see examples and usage here: https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealdb/installation/running/memory
